# Dual boot laptop boots straight to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Lenovo G580 which had Windows 8 (with UEFI) preinstalled. I got sick of the OS and tried installing Ubuntu alongside using this tutorial :

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html?m=1

My problem is that the laptop boots directly into Ubuntu. I tried using boot repair in Ubuntu, which asked me to disable secure boot.I ticked yes.Then it gave me the following screen :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5q64RDDKM9Zlpna1RnOUowam8/view?usp=docslist_api

And as shown in the image I opened the url (paste.ubuntu.com/12632198/), but I could not understand what was the page

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo parted -l` terminal command.

Comment: You show two efi partiitons sda1 & sda2. Only sda2 is the ESP - efi system partition and sda3 is a vendor hidden partition with some eif boot files. Use gparted and remove boot flag from sda1. You also are missing an UEFI entry for Windows, which you may want to add. Not sure if Windows will add that back or not?

Answer (score 0):

The report generated by boot repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/12632198/ tells you the following information:

```
=================== /etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

See the line saying `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` ? This tells the boot loader to *not* show OS selection menu. Open the terminal, type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to open that file with nano text editor, and change line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` to `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`. Save file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>O</kbd> and exit with kbd>Ctrl +<kbd>X</kbd>. Finally run `sudo update-grub` and restart the laptop. You now should be able to see OS selection window upon boot